# Javascript order div's by data value highest first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have this code. If you look at the data, the id is the id of the div's.
Then next is the hovers field each has a numberical value.

The code below will increment the hovers each time a div is hovered.

```
var counter = [
    {id: 1, hovers: 1},
    {id: 2, hovers: 0},
    {id: 3, hovers: 8},
    {id: 4, hovers: 5},
    {id: 5, hovers: 3},
    {id: 6, hovers: 4},
    {id: 7, hovers: 2},
    {id: 8, hovers: 9},
    {id: 9, hovers: 2}
]

$('div').mouseover(function() {
  var obj = counter.find(e => e.id == $(this).attr('id'))
  if(obj) obj.hovers++
  console.log(obj)
})
```

Here are the html div's that have being hovered and counter.

```
<div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
<div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
<div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
<div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
<div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
<div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
```

If we look at the counter data.

How can I move the div's so that the one with most hovers goes first and in that order with the others?

Comment: So you want it to reorder itself on every hover?

Comment: No, that would be too much. Maybe reorder on a button click?

Comment: You can consider using flexbox for reordering: `flex-direction: <axis>-reverse`, e.g. `flex-direction: column-reverse` and setting the `order` attribute of each div as the number of hover events detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting task, here's my solution:

(Note I used `click` event to see more controllable action; change event to whatever you need)

When you click an element, counter increments and all elements reorder accordingly. The highest value is on the top (change it inside `sort` function if needed).

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('div');

const counter = [
    {id: 1, hovers: 1},
    {id: 2, hovers: 0},
    {id: 3, hovers: 8},
    {id: 4, hovers: 5},
    {id: 5, hovers: 3},
    {id: 6, hovers: 4},
    {id: 7, hovers: 2},
    {id: 8, hovers: 9},
    {id: 9, hovers: 2}
];

const cMap = new Map(); // create a map for convenience
for (const el of counter) {
  cMap.set(el.id, el.hovers);
}

for (const el of els) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() { // change event to a different one if needed
    const id = parseInt(el.id);
    cMap.set(id, cMap.get(id) + 1);
    el.innerHTML = '<p>Box ' + id + '; hovers: ' + cMap.get(id) + '</p>';

    const sortedIds = [...new Map([...cMap.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])).keys()];
   
    const b = document.body;
    while (b.firstChild) { b.removeChild(b.firstChild); }; // clear body
    for (const i of sortedIds) {
      for (const el of els) { if (el.id == i) b.appendChild(el); } // append divs in order
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
<div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
<div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
<div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
<div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
<div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

So what you're trying to do is actually very expensive. Using your current data structures, you would have to sort `counter` array each time a mouseover happens to maintain the proper order. This means that, if you had `N` mouse overs and `M` items in `counter`, the time complexity for this operation would be `O(N*MlogM)`.

There's also the perf hit of searching through the array every time a hover happens.

Assuming the frequency in which you need this sorted list is much less than the amount of hovers, you could just do the sort when you need it instead of on each hover.

Additionally, you can keep your data in a `Map<id, hoverCount>` instead of an array, to make the hover update a constant time operation. This would also allow using any JS value as an id and not just numbers.

```
const counter = new Map([
  [1, 1],
  [2, 0],
  [3, 8],
  [4, 5],
  [5, 3],
  [6, 4],
  [7, 2],
  [8, 9],
  [9, 2]
]);

$('div').mouseover(function() {
  const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
  if (counter.has(id)) {
    counter.set(id, counter.get(id) + 1);
  }
});
```

If you know for a fact that your ids will match index value - 1 for each element, as they do now, then there's no need for a map nor to iterate through the array, just use the id as the index for instant access:

```
$('div').mouseover(function() {
  const idx = Number($(this).attr('id')) - 1;
  if (idx >= 0 && idx < counter.length) {
    counter[idx].hovers += 1;
  }
});
```

As far as sorting, it's just a matter of comparing the `hovers` property of each element:

```
// sorting the Map
getSorted() {
  return [...counter.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
}

// sorting the array of <id, hovers> objects
getSorted() {
  return counter.sort((a, b) => b.hovers - a.hovers));
}
```

Comment: note that this sort function won't give you the descending order of your array, but this one will: `counter.sort((a, b) => b.hovers - a.hovers)`